# Proof that a Polynomial is Irreducible

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

In my abstract algebra class, we were given some polynomials to prove irreducible or not over the rationals.  I have come up with a proof for this one, but I'm not sure if it's valid.

The polynomial: $$x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$$

I've started by taking the modulus $2$ of all the coefficients to get:

$$x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$$There's a theorem in my book that says if you take the modulus using a prime and the new polynomial has the same degree and is irreducible, than the previous polynomial is also irreducible.

So to prove $x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible:

If it is reducible it can be written as $f(x)g(x)$.  But because it has a constant term, both $f$ and $g$ must have a constant term.  But this also implies neither $f$ nor $g$ can have an $x^3$ term because their product does not have an $x^3$ term.  But since the product has an $x^4$ term, they both must have $x^2$ terms.  Also, since the product has an $x$ term, at least one of $f$ and $g$ must have an $x$ term.  But then the $x$ term times the $x^2$ term in the other would make an $x^3$ term, which the product does not have, so $f$ and $g$ cannot exist.

Is this proof solid?  Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: There appears to be a typo,\ (or error), the first polynomial has root $\, x = -1\ $ (which remains a root mod $\,2).\ \ $

Comment: The product f(x)g(x) not having an x^3 term does not imply f,g do not have an x^3 term. Nor does it having an x^4 term imply f,g both have x^2 terms.

Comment: Both $f$ and $g$ could have cubic terms which are eliminated under some sort of cancellation when they're multiplied.

Comment: Did you try the rational roots test?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a typo, and the polynomial is really $x^4 - 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$? Because this one is reducible modulo $2$, but irreducible modulo $3$.

Comment: The reasoning is flawed from the start. $p(x)=x^2+1$ is irreducible (over the rationals), it has the same degree as $q(x)=x^2+2x+1$, you get $p$ from $q$ by reducing modulo the prime 2, but $q$ isn't irreducible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, $x^4+x^2+x+1$ is not irreducible in the two element field, since $x=1$ is a root.

And the polynomial you started with is not irreducible over the rationals, since $x=-1$ is a root. Thus the polynomial $x^4+2x^3+x^2+x+1$ is divisible by $x+1$.

**Remark:** We have $x^4+2x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$. The polynomial $x^3+x^2+1$ *is* irreducible over the rationals. For a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ is irreducible over a field $F$ if and only if it has no root in that field. And by the Rational Roots Theorem, the polynomial $x^3+x^2+1$ has no rational roots.

Comment: How is $x = 1$ a root of $x^4+x^2+x+1$?

Comment: @IvoBeckers, modulo $2$.